# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blog.roles' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I clone a project. When I run `composer install` I got this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'axie.roles' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `roles` where `id` = 3 and `guard_name` = web limit 1)
```

even If I run this commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload
composer install
composer update
php artisan migrate
```

Still got the same error..

Comment: Make sure u have `roles` table in your database, first migrate then update

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have migration adding `roles` table in your `database/migrations` folder.

Also check if you are connecting to correct database (you can see it with `DB::connection()->getConfig()` command). If not edit correctly `.env` file.